# ZetaSQL - Creating a simple catalog with tables and columns using local service

Tags: parsing, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-lineage

We are using a Python client binding for ZetaSQL GRPC [local service](https://github.com/google/zetasql/tree/master/zetasql/local_service) in our application to analyze statements and extract referenced tables and output columns.

It is possible to extract referenced tables using the following simplified Python code and the local service:

```py
import zetasql.local_service as zql

conn = zql.connect()

language_options = conn.GetLanguageOptions(
    zql.pb2.LanguageOptionsRequest(maximum_features=True)
)

# Used to allow ZetaSQL parser to parse `CREATE TABLE AS` statments
language_options.supported_statement_kinds.pop()
req = zql.pb2.ExtractTableNamesFromStatementRequest(
    sql_statement=sql, options=language_options
)
res = conn.ExtractTableNamesFromStatement(req)
return json.loads(MessageToJson(res))
```

However, from what I see [here](https://github.com/google/zetasql/blob/master/zetasql/local_service/local_service.proto), the local service doesn't have the full functionalities of the Java client, mainly creating simple catalog with tables and columns to analyze any SQL statement. Also setting analyzer options doesn't seem to be [possible](https://github.com/google/zetasql/blob/master/zetasql/local_service/local_service.proto#L749).

Is it possible to analyze SQL statements using ZetaSQL with only the local service? If not, what should be the alternative approach to extract output columns?